# Sphinxsearch and php next prev functionality

Tags: php, sphinx, paging

I am using sphinxsearch + php for full text search in my app.

I need next prev buttons on my product page. For example I run query "Men shoes" it returns me result of 20 shoes (paging limit is 20), then I click into product and open up a product page, and here I have next and previous products. But next and prev should work to specific to my search query "Men shoes". I store my query in session, and I have ID of product. So how can I find the position of these product and increment or decrement it find products I need.

Is it possible to without query-ing the whole table and looping through to find what I need.

Answer (score 0):

While you can* create a cursor solution, it may be simpler to just use offset.

Page 1 is offset zero, page 2 is offset 20, page 3 is 40 and so on.

where you call `setLimits`, you can set the offset.

---

*Basically you need a consistent sort order, and need to store the value of the column, as the 'cursor' for paging, and use it for filtering the next page. If sorting by weight, you store the weight of the last result on the page. Then for the next page, you only want weights bedlow that one. (with weights is even more complicated as there can be many results with the same weight, so you need to do multi-column sorting)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't quite understand. If we take offset solution i can get 20 results store them, and go next through those 20, but what happens when I reach to the end of the page (lets say 0-20), so if I am on 20th item, I don`t have the next one.

Comment: I dont understand your question. Perhaps could offer this: http://nearby.org.uk/sphinx/search-example5-withcomments.phps - a fully functional front end, with code showing how to page the results.